# serverless(node-aws) "TypeError","errorMessage":"callback is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

on my `handler.js`

```
'use strict';
var lalamove = require('./lalamove/index.js');

module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
  lalamove.getQuotation("hi");
};
```

I have been passing the string "hi" to `getQuotation()` on `lalamove/index.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    getQuotation: function(event,context,callback){
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: event })
          }
        console.log('response', response);
        callback(null,response.body);
    }
}
```

and it logs in the console log. it works in the console but it can't be returned. when I check the logs:

> ERROR      Invoke Error    {"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"callback is not afunction","stack":["TypeError: callback is not a function","    at Object.getQuotation (/var/task/lalamove/index.js:10:9)","    at Runtime.module.exports.getEstimate[as handler] (/var/task/handler.js:14:12)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:63:25)","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"]}

I tried to remove `context` but it's still the same, I tried to use `return` instead of `callback` but it does not work, I still get:

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

instead of

```
{ statusCode: 200, body: '{"message":"hi"}' }
```

Comment: I am really not sure but I faced similar issue once. Please try passing response instead of response.body in the callback

Comment: @SiddharthYadav already tried that, didn't work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get response you have you implement callback function on caller function like below.

```
'use strict';
var lalamove = require('./lalamove/index.js');

module.exports.getEstimate = (event, context, callback) => {
  lalamove.getQuotation("hi", context, function(response) {
       console.log(response)//it will print return value
   });
};
```

Comment: sadly it does not work. it will print in console but not on as return of the function

Comment: Please pass second parameters as well. `lalamove.getQuotation("hi", 'context', function(response) {`

Comment: sorry, I have copy pasted your answer but it returns `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

Comment: Please check once again. You are missing something. It works for me.